# How can I call multiple pages from a single method of DefaultController.php in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Following is my code for calling just one page from one method but I want to call multiple pages from a single method.I want to call all the pages like 'Video Listing','Contact Information','Business Description',etc from cmsAction().

```
namespace Atpl\FrontBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/",name="atpl_front_index")
     * @Template()
     * */
    public function indexAction() {
        $name = "test";
        $data = array('name' => $name);
        return $this->render('AtplFrontBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $data);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/cms/{page}",name="atpl_default_cms")
     * @Template()
     * */
    public function cmsAction($page) {

        $data = array('page' => $page);
        return $this->render('AtplFrontBundle:Default:cms.html.twig', $data);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/dashboard/",name="atpl_default_dashboard")
     * @Template()
     * */
    public function dashAction() {

        $dash = "This is Dashboard.";
        $data = array('dash' => $dash);
        return $this->render('AtplFrontBundle:Default:dashboard.html.twig', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can render another controller into your twig file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follow :

Now u have need of  two action :

first action  :

```
/**
 * @Route("/list",name="list")
 * @Template()
 * */
public function listAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $pagesData = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:TablePages')->findAll(); 

       return $this->render('YourBundle:Default:list.html.twig',array('pages' => $pagesData));
    } 
}
```

Here 'TablePages' is your entity class name ..

second action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/pageShow",name="page_show")
 * @Template()
 * */
public function pageShowAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $pageData = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:TablePages')->find($id); 

       return $this->render('YourBundle:Default:show.html.twig',array('page' => $pageData));
    } 
}
```

Now in your have two twig files:

List Twig :

```
 <!--src/YourBundle/Resources/views/Default/list.html.twig -->
 <! -- fetching the pages data listing -->
 {% page in pagesData %}
    <a href = "{{ path('page_show',{'id' : page.id }) }}">{{ page.yourTitleonNameField }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

Here 'yourTitleonNameField'  is the field name through which you recognize the page ...
Show Twig:

```
<!--src/YourBundle/Resources/views/Default/show.html.twig -->
 <! -- showing the individual page -->
 {{ page.id }}
 {{ page.otherEntityAttributes }}
 ........
```

I hope it will help to you ..

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer..but it is not working properly..The links 'Video Listing','Contact Information',etc are on 'dashboard.html.twig'.By clicking on the pages the content should be changed and remain on the same page.What should I do for that..?

Comment: Then u will have to redirect your different routes of different listing item on the dashboard.html.twig ...because u can't render more than one template in one method

Comment: Hey Ajeet,actually I have a table called 'tbl_pages' which contains some data.I have created entity for that.Now I want to get the data from database.What should I change in entity/model(tbl_pages.php) and Controller (DefaultController.php)..?

Comment: Here is my Controller (DefaultController.php) file.
class DefaultController extends Controller {
public function dashAction($page) {
        if ($page == "") {
            $data = array('dash' => "This is Dashboard.");
            return $this->render('AtplFrontBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $data);
        } 
and like this all the other links are given.

Comment: Do u want to fetch data from just one table ?

Comment: Yes...I have put another post for that with the detailed code.